# Error occured while packaging the kivymd application

Tags: kivy, packaging, buildozer, kivymd

I am packaging kivyMD app in Google colab. The app is source code of kitchen sink app from [official github page of kivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/tree/master/demos/kitchen_sink).

Edit: Error occured after : `!buildozer -v android debug`

```
# Package the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1047, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 205, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 990, in build_package
    version = self.buildozer.get_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 701, in get_version
    with open(fn) as fd:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './../../kivymd/__init__.py'
```

*Full Output + Error [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ChhbbzSeKtzWcy1qd8uFq5o4RX4J4lPQ/view?usp=sharing)*

Info: [File Structure is same as source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iyNx.png)

What should I do to handle this error.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
```

For this command you have to use usb debugging with your phone .